# Difference between openMP's target and target data?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

The target construct offloads a code region from host to a target device. 
The variables `p`,`v1`,`v2`, are explicitly mapped to the the target device using the map clause.
target data also does the same ,

Then what is implied by :

- "The construct creates variables that will persist throughout the
  target data region "
- "New device data environment creation"

in regard to the  "target data" construct,

I mean what differences are there in offloading mechanism amongst these codes :

```
void vec_mult1(float *p, float *v1, float *v2, int N)
{
    int i;
    init(v1, v2, N);
#pragma omp target map(to: v1[0:N], v2[:N]) map(from: p[0:N])
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
        p[i] = v1[i] * v2[i];
    output(p, N);
}


void vec_mult2(float *p, float *v1, float *v2, int N)
{
    int i;
    init(v1, v2, N);
#pragma omp target device(mic0) data map(to: v1[0:N], v2[:N]) map(from: p[0:N])
    {
    //this code runs on accelerator card
#pragma omp target //if we omit it what difference will it make ? 
#pragma omp parallel for
        for (i=0; i<N; i++)
            p[i] = v1[i] * v2[i];
    }
    output(p, N);
}

void vec_mult3(float *p, float *v1, float *v2, int N)
{
    int i;
    init(v1, v2, N);
#pragma omp target data map(to: v1[0:N], v2[:N]) map(from: p[0:N])
    {

        //target construct omitted
#pragma omp parallel for
        for (i=0; i<N; i++)
            p[i] = v1[i] * v2[i];
    }
    output(p, N);
}
```

I tried to execute them but I'm unable to notice significant differences between them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `target data` construct only creates a device data environment that lasts for the extent of the region. It only sets the mapping between the variables in the device data environment and the data environment of the encountering task. The rationale behind having a separate construct is that in many cases it is desirable that certain data remains on the device instead of constantly being transferred to and from it.

Imagine the following very artificial example:

```
int data[N];

#pragma omp target
#pragma omp for
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
   data[i] *= 2;

// Do something else

#pragma omp target
#pragma omp for
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
   data[i] += 5;
```

Now in that case, the two `target` constructs also create two data environments. The `data` variable is automatically mapped as `tofrom`. That means the following set of actions takes place:

1. `data` is copied to the device
2. The first loop runs on the  device
3. `data` is copied from the device
4. The host executes `// Do something else`
5. `data` is copied to the device
6. The second loop runs on the device
7. `data` is copied from the device

Now imagine that `// Do something else` reads `data` but never modifies it. That makes the transfer of `data` to the device in step 5 redundant - it could just be retained in the state it has after step 2. Here is where the `target data` construct comes into play. It allows you to create a data environment that spans more than the extent of the `target` construct. The example above can then be rewritten so:

```
int data[N];

#pragma omp target data map(tofrom: data)
{
   #pragma omp target
   #pragma omp for
   for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
      data[i] *= 2;

   #pragma omp target update from(data)

   // Do something else

   #pragma omp target
   #pragma omp for
   for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
      data[i] += 5;
}
```

The `target` constructs in that case do not create new device data environments but rather utilise the one created by the `target data` construct (actually they do create new data environments, but those are merged with the one from the `target data` and they do not contain any new references). So the sequence of operations is:

1. `data` is copied to the device
2. The first loop runs on the device
3. `data` is explicitly copied from the device
4. The host executes `// Do something else`
5. The second loop runs on the device
6. `data` is copied from the device

Since `data` is needed in `// Do something else` but it is only automatically transferred from the device at the end of the `target data` construct, the explicit `target update` is used to copy it into the encountering task's data environment at step 3.

Now this is just a small and very artificial example but in real life saving on unnecessary data transfers could significantly improve the performance of OpenMP applications that offload computations to co-processors and/or accelerators.

Answer (score 1):

`#pragma omp target data` only maps the variables to target device, but it doesn't execute any code on target device. `#pragma omp target` maps the variables and executes the target region on target device.

So, in your example:

- vec_mult1 and vec_mult2 will execute the loop on target;
- vec_mult3 will map variables to target but execute the loop on host.