# How can I edit device variables in OpenMP?

Tags: c++, c, parallel-processing, gpu, openmp

The problem is quite simple: I'm trying to edit the value of a variable inside a **target data** region in OpenMP, but whatever I do, I'm editing the host variable, not the one in the device's memory.

Check out this very simple code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main() {
  int sum;
  sum = 0;

  #pragma omp target data map(tofrom: sum)
  {

    printf("Initial value = %d\n", sum);
  
    sum = 1; // This seems to edit host's variable, not the copy in device's memory
    
    printf("Inside data region value = %d\n", sum);
  }
  
  printf("Outside data region value = %d\n", sum);

  return 0;
}
```

The execution outputs as follows:

```
Initial value = 0
Inside data region value = 1
Outside data region value = 0
```

I believe that what is happening is that I'm editing the variable in the host, therefore, the device variable remains at 0, and when the data region exists that 0 overwrites the 1 that was on the host (because it is mapped with the tofrom clause). I have tried every clause I now in order to edit the variable in the device, here are some examples:

```
#pragma omp target
sum = 1;
```

```
#pragma omp target
#pragma omp single
sum = 1;
```

```
#pragma omp target data use_device_addr(sum)
sum = 1;
```

```
#pragma omp target data use_device_ptr(sum)
sum = 1;
```

```
#pragma omp target data use_device_addr(sum)
{
#pragma omp target
#pragma omp single
sum = 1;
}
```

```
#pragma omp target is_device_ptr(sum)
sum = 1;
```

```
#pragma omp target has_device_addr(sum)
sum = 1;
```

Literally half of them return errors or segmentation fault, and the others don't seem to work as the last printf is always 0, instead of 1.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22247855/difference-between-openmps-target-and-target-data) help?

Comment: Hey Laci, thank you, that helps, although now I'm trying to find out another thing, I'll make another post.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so it seems impossible to do what I was trying to do so the closest thing that I've found (thanks to Laci) is the use of #pragma omp target update, which explicitely moves data from or to the device and the host.

So the code above could be done by using:

```
#pragma omp target update from(sum) // copies sum from device to host
sum = 1; // edits host's sum, which has just been updated with the latest device value
#pragma omp target update to(sum) // copies sum to the device
```

Just as a note, in case you want to move arrays you must indicate the size, for example:

```
int* array = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * N);

#pragma omp target update to(array[:N])
```